# Stock and Out Of Stock filter in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, layered-navigation

I try to add Stock and Out Of Stock filter in the Layered Navigation.
I set the configuration of the attribute **"quantity_and_stock_status"**:

[image]

In the storefront I look the filter, but if the configuration -> **Display Product out of Stock** is enabled it counts all items without stock status condition.

I have seen the following in the code. Magento does not filter if the option **Display Product out of Stock** is enabled.

```
  if (!$this->inventoryConfig->isShowOutOfStock($currentScopeId)) {
        $select->where('stock_index.stock_status = ?', Stock::STOCK_IN_STOCK);
    }
```

I have tried to replace this class but the methods are private and it gives error.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Have you able to show the Stock filter on layer navigation?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to change that single line of code
`$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock');`
is called throughout the code in different ways and manners.
The best approach would be to find every single call for this config and change it with plugins or preference if the methods are private, which they mostly are as it seems.
Or you could do the worst hack in magento history and take the laziest approach, where you create a plugin for `Magento\Framework\App\Config` and check if the path is `'cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock' && your_custom_case` and return true of false based on your needs.